# Pattern generated by selenium IDE is always wrong?

Tags: php, regex, selenium, phpunit, preg-match

I'm writing selenium test cases in php by exporting it from selenium IDE. Whenever i use verifyText in IDE it generates `preg_match` assertion in php which get fails for all the different cases. Here is one of them,

```
try {
    $this->assertTrue((bool)preg_match('/^exact:Wachtwoord vergeten[\s\S]$/',$this->getText("link=exact:Wachtwoord vergeten?")));
} catch (PHPUnit_Framework_AssertionFailedError $e) {
        array_push($this->selenium->verificationErrors, $e->toString());
}
```

The script is automatically generated from selenium IDE. I'm clueless what i'm doing wrong or is there any change that i can do in IDE to make this right? Since it is getting generated automatically from IDE i don't want to make changes in the code to fix it.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: wat do u mean by  `get fails for all the different cases`?

Comment: I mean it fails everytime when the script(automatically generated) has preg_match in it.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the getText result doesn't match what you're looking for. You could try [this url](http://www.phpliveregex.com/) and compare your search string (^exact:Wachtwoord vergeten[\s\S]$) with the result from getText(). It often happened to me, and the solution was to simply remove the 'exact:' string from my search string.
In your case:

```
try {
    $this->assertTrue((bool)preg_match('/^Wachtwoord vergeten[\s\S]$/',$this->getText("link=exact:Wachtwoord vergeten?")));
} catch (PHPUnit_Framework_AssertionFailedError $e) {
        array_push($this->selenium->verificationErrors, $e->toString());
}
```

Comment: I know that the pattern we are matching with string is wrong. But this code is auto generated from selenium IDE and instead of correcting in the code everytime, i want to know is there any way i can get correct pattern from selenium IDE